# How do I change particular component in TFS workitem template

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'd like to change the source of a particular component withing a workitem in TFS (latest version of the solution).

I do not mean to change the workitem's xml representation to just reposition/createnew/whatever the existing components.

Example: I'd like to make change to the history component so that it shows subset of all the changes made, comments only for example. I'd also like all the comments to be shown in different design. Simply put, I want to recode the existing components.

Is there an easy way or only the TFS SDK way ? Or another ?

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are asking is is there another way to show a custom history view without using TFS SDK IE TFS API to modify the control type in this case WorkItemLogControl?

```
<Tab Label="History">
  <Control Type="WorkItemLogControl" FieldName="System.History" Label="&History:" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" /> 
  </Tab>
```

I am not aware of a way to do that (modify built-in types).

Take a look at this sample project that will give you an idea of how to modify your template using the API:  [click me](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/02/11/tfs-api-part-14-export-work-item-definition.aspx).  Another option is to export the template and save it locally and then import it back.

If you want, you can create your own work item control though.  Here is a walk-though on how to do that:

[Part 1](http://nickhoggard.wordpress.com/2009/11/12/tfs-2010-beta-2-custom-work-item-controls-step-1-getting-started/)

[Part 2](http://nickhoggard.wordpress.com/2009/11/14/tfs-2010-beta-2-%E2%80%93-custom-work-item-controls-step-2-work-item-setup/)

Here are a few additional examples that can get you started on creating your own:

http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/releases/view/7240